# Get oracle Java Stored Procedure to return a table

Tags: java, oracle, java-stored-procedures

I am trying to write an oracle Java stored procedure to return a data structure that can be used as a table to so selects against.  The final outcome must look something like this:

```
select * from TABLE(get_table('astring','anotherstring'));
```

I have defined the oracle types like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE  "TEST_JAVA_TYPE" IS OBJECT ( 
  name                  VARCHAR2(255),
  value                 VARCHAR2(255)
)
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "TEST_JAVA_TYPE_TABLE" AS TABLE OF TEST_JAVA_TYPE;
```

My java code looks like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TableTester {

public static ARRAY getTable() {
    List<TEST_JAVA_TYPE> list = new ArrayList<TEST_JAVA_TYPE>();
    TEST_JAVA_TYPE t1 = new TEST_JAVA_TYPE();
    TEST_JAVA_TYPE t2 = new TEST_JAVA_TYPE();
    t1.name = "Joe";
    t1.value = "A";
    t2.name = "Jim";
    t2.value = "B"; 
    list.add(t1);
    list.add(t2);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:default:connection:");   
    ArrayDescriptor dsc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("TEST_JAVA_TYPE_TABLE", conn);  

    return new ARRAY(dsc, conn, list.toArray()); 
}

static class TEST_JAVA_TYPE {
    public String name;
    public String value;
}

}
```

And I call the java code like this:

```
FUNCTION get_table(conn_type VARCHAR2, cube_name VARCHAR2) RETURN                
TEST_JAVA_TYPE_TABLE AS LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'TableTester.getTable() return oracle.sql.ARRAY';
```

When I run this I get

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected a Java type at argument position 2 to which some Oracle value can be converted got something else
```

How do i convert/map  this properly?